# Overwiting a File

Tags: vb.net

This is a bit complicated, but I would like to take a screenshot of the screen, as well as saving it. But when I am saving the same one, I would like to overwrite it, but my coding is not working.

I wonder if anyone has any idea of what I am doing wrong:

```
Dim bmpScreenShot As Bitmap
Dim gfxScreenshot As Graphics

bmpScreenShot = New Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height)

    gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenShot)
    gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)
    MessageBox.Show("This will save the log as a screenshot in the 'S' Drive (S:/), please make sure that this drive has been mapped in your network.", "Log Saving", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

    If System.IO.File.Exists("S:\My Behaviour Logs\Incident Details.bmp") Then
        bmpScreenShot.Save("S:\My Behaviour Logs\Incident Details.jpeg", Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        System.IO.File.Replace("S:\My Behaviour Logs\Incident Details.bmp", "S:\My Behaviour Logs\Incident Details.jpeg", "S:\My Behaviour Logs\Incident Details.jpeg")

        If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists("S:\My Behaviour Logs")) Then
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("S:\My Behaviour Logs")
        End If
    End If
```

If anyone has any idea what I am doing wrong, please say.

Thank You

Comment: You cannot save to or delete the file while a `Bitmap` image is open from that file.  NET keeps the file open while the bmp exists.  Use Clone to make a new bitmap.

Comment: When you say it is not working, what do you mean? Do you get an exception?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply, but how do you make a clone of the image, hopefully that should solve my problem. Thanks